# Getting Intellisense on the interface that a method implements if that method does not have its own XML comments

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, xml-comments

In Visual Studio 2010 is there a way to get Intellisense on the Interface that a method implements if that method does not have any XML comments of its own?

I suppose something like this would be fairly useful. I like to include XML comments with the interface and don't like to repeat (copy) the same text at every implementing method. Only when something specific to the implementing method needs to be described, I give the method its own XML comments.

Comment: Do you mean the data coming out of XML comments?

Comment: Yeah I mean the embedded XML comments in the source code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have ReSharper you can just use Ctrl+Shift+F1 to show the short help of method.
If that method does not have any XML comments the help of its interface is shown.
I do not have enough reputation to give you a screenshot. So I show you my code and explain it:

```
internal interface ISomeInterface  
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Integer1 help text by interface.
  /// </summary>
  int Integer1 { get; set; }
}

internal class Class2 : ISomeInterface
{
  public int Integer1 { get; set; }

  public int CallInterface1( )
  {
    return Integer1; // <- Place cursor on Integer1 and press Ctrl+Shift+F1
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have enough reputation now ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Resharper. If you put your cursor on a method declaration that has no XML comment, Rehsarper offers you to automatially copy the comment from the base method.

Comment: I don't want to copy the comment, I just want to see the information in the small popup windows. The whole point is to not have the comments on a method when it has nothing to add to the comments already included with the interface.